# Add different Buttons on a single column of a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've added an Edit button to the `Action` column of my `Gridview` using a `TemplateField`. I want every column to have the edit button in the first column except for the last row, which should have an Add button there instead. How would I implement this separate last row with the different button? Here is the code I have.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" text="Edit" OnClientClick="btnEditClick()" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Action");
DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
...
dt.Rows.Add(row1);
gridRoles.DataSource = dt;
gridRoles.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add 2 button 1st Edit(visible) and 2nd Add (make it display=none initially)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" text="Edit" OnClientClick="btnEditClick()" />
  <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" text="Edit" OnClientClick="AddClick()" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then Find Gridview Last row and find the Button Controls

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count-1];
Button Edit = ((Button)row.FindControl("btnedit")).Text;
Button Add = ((Button)row.FindControl("btnadd")).Text;
Edit.visible =false;
Add.Visible =true;
```

Here reverse the button display option : `False for Edit and true for Add`

Answer (score 0):

That item template column is going to add whatever it's contents are to every row.  One way around this is to add and empty column, and add your button during the OnRowDataBound event.

You can check to see if you are on the last row, and if so, add the other button, rather than the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the footer as the last line of the GridView. It could look like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" ... >
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" text="Edit" OnClientClick="btnEditClick()" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" text="Add" OnClientClick="btnAddClick()" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>    
    ....
</asp:GridView>
```

You can look at this article for a complete example, with input controls and validation: [Inserting a New Record from the GridView's Footer](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-vb).